# How can one calculate the Möbius function $\mu(a_1,a_i)$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., 10\}$ of this poset?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, mobius-function

I've seen this partially ordered set in our combinatorics script and it says that it is obvious how to calculate the möbius function $\mu(a_1,a_i)$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., 10\}$.

Here's the Hasse diagram of the Poset, but I don't know how to calculate the möbius function.

[image]

I know that the möbius function is multiplicative and that the sum of the Möbius function over all positive divisors of $n$ is  zero except when $n=1$. But that still doesn't help me.

Comment: Start with $\mu\left(a_1, a_1\right) = 1$ (a consequence of one of the axioms) and then work your way up the poset using the equality $\sum_{a_j \in \left[a_1, a_i\right]} \mu\left(a_1, a_j\right) = 0$ for all $j \neq 1$ (also a consequence of one of the axioms). This is not rocket science, and the computation won't take more than a few minutes. But you can also simplify your life by realizing that many of the intervals $\left[a_1, a_j\right]$ are boolean algebras or products of chains, which lets you immediately find their Möbius functions.

Comment: Also note that you are using knowledge of the Möbius function for the partial order of positive intergers defined by divisiblity (what is what many people know as the only Möbius function) to a totally different problem. For example, stating that the Möbius functions is multiplicative does not make sense for the given poset. For actual solution advode, darij's comment is of course very good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing two different (but related) meanings of the term *Möbius function*: the number-theoretic Möbius function and the poset-theoretic Möbius function.

The poset-theoretic Möbius function is defined recursively on interval $[x,y]$ of a poset as follows: $\mu([x,x]) = 1$ and when $x < y$,
$$
\mu([x,y]) = - \sum_{x \leq z < y} \mu([x,z]).
$$

One famous poset is the divisibility poset, in which the elements are the natural numbers (excluding zero), and $x \leq y$ if $x \mid y$ (i.e., if $x$ divides $y$). This poset is self-similar, in the sense that the subposet consisting of all elements above some $x$ is isomorphic to the entire poset, and for this reason $\mu([x,y])$ depends only on $y/x$, i.e., there is a function $\mu_{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\mu([x,y]) = \mu_{\mathbb{N}}(y/x)$. This function is the number-theoretic Möbius function.